# blackberry background or wallpaper using java

Tags: blackberry, java-me, background, wallpaper

how to set an img in your application as a blackberry background"wallpaper"?
img is in the res folder 
i read that you can use 
HomeScreen.setBackgroundImag(uri)

but the img shall be in the blackberry device it self is there any ideas??
i used this code

```
Background bc = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(backGround);
       this.getMainManager().setBackground(bc);
```

but it works as a background for the application not the blackberry device it self

Answer (score 0):

I am giving some example try this method ,call this method in main manager

public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        //Draw the background image and then call paint.

```
graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, w,120, Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Player_bg.png"), 0, 0);
    super.paint(graphics);
```

Comment: i found the solution for making a background u need first to copy the image in your application to the store of the blackberry device then u need to read it and make it a background using the HomeScreen .setBackGround thanks alot Kamal